# Problems with sound w/ HP elitebook 2540p

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hp

Hello people of AskUbuntu!

I have installed the latest version of Ubuntu on my laptop, everything works perfectly apart from the fact that I have no sound! Ive tried the speaker test terminal code and I don't hear a thing.

I have searched high and low for solutions but I don't think Ive come across one. The internal laptop sound card seems to be recognized but perhaps it hasn't been assigned or something.

writing    **`aplay -l`** in the terminal gives me this:

***List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices***

```
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 0: 92HD75B3X5 Analog [92HD75B3X5 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

also typing **`lsmod | grep snd`** gives me...

```
<code>snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  2
snd_hda_codec_idt      57344  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_idt
snd_hda_intel          36864  4
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    81920  18 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
soundcore              16384  1 snd
</code>
```

Any suggestions on what to do about this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks